# Database backup strategy

Tags: mysql

I will like to seek some advice from the public regarding the backup of database strategy. My team is using mysql database for our application and I will to hear opinions on how we can perform database backup or is there any open source platform that can achieve it with an user interface?

My idea as of now is to actually use jenkins to act as a scheduler to run the script to backup but that means I will have to manually manage the backup. At the same time, I was thinking to be future-proof in the sense that if there is another application that we have to manage that will run on another popular database such as postgres. Have anyone used some database backup strategy that is nice to use with a user interface?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to roll your own, and certainly don't use Jenkins as a scheduler. See [Backup and Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html) in the MySQL docs.

Comment: The question asks about method - strategy is different eg daily at close of business, prior to upgrade etc

Comment: Method:  mysqldump (or similar); LVM (very quick); Replication (using Replica as a 'continual' backup); Clustering (covers most scenarios); etc.